# Warnings when building a .NET application using Google API

Tags: .net

I've an application that uses Google Drive API with .NET 4.0. When I build the application I get three warnings:

> Warning 3 Unable to find dependency 'GOOGLE.APIS' (Signature='(null)'
>   Version='1.8.1.31687') of assembly 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.dll'
>   D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FFP Extended
>   1.0\FFPXInstaller\FFPXInstaller.vdproj
>
> Warning 2 Unable to find dependency 'GOOGLE.APIS.CORE'
>   (Signature='(null)' Version='1.8.1.31685') of assembly
>   'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.dll' D:\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FFP Extended 1.0\FFPXInstaller\FFPXInstaller.vdproj
>
> Warning 1 Unable to find dependency 'ZLIB.PORTABLE'
>   (Signature='(null)' Version='1.9.1.9000') of assembly
>   'Google.Apis.dll' D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FFP
>   Extended 1.0\FFPXInstaller\FFPXInstaller.vdproj

The installed application seems to work fine, but, obviously, I'd rather not have any warning when it's compiled. Has anyone seen anything similar? If so, have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The installer project `FFPXInstaller.vdproj` has some references to the assemblies mentioned in the warnings. Probably these files are from a prerequisite that reside in another folder then specified in the project, or don't exist at all.

Check the project references to see what goes wrong. Check if the assemblies with a warning sign actually exist in the path specified and that their versions match. If not, download them. and place them in the right folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply; I've had a look in the .vdproj files and the files are referenced there. The files do exist in the paths but their versions are later than the ones specified in the .vdproj files - for example, Google.Apis.Core has version 1.8.2. I presume the

Comment: @user3855989: If you have more questions, please let me know. If not, since you are new, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark before the question you liked best if it has been useful to you.

Comment: Sorry, it timed out before I complete the comment; I added my comment below.

Comment: thanks for the reply; I've had a look in the .vdproj files and found the references to the "missing" files.

The files do exist in the packages folder of the application - the path in the vdproj file start with "8:" - I don't know how to interpet that!

Also the dll versions are later than the ones specified in the warning messages. For example, Google.Apis.dll is referenced in the vdproj file as 1.8.2.23762, which matches what's in the packages folder but doesn't match the warning version of 1.8.1.31687.